# Python library for continuous integration testing

Tags: python, continuous-integration, integration-testing

I'm trying to make a testing system for continuous integration and I want to be able to have checks that do specific operations, like formatting files in a specific way, and those checks need to have a flow to them.

Example:

```
FormatFilesCheck(files):
    Test(see if formatter is installed)
    for prep in prework:
        Test(do prep)
        for file in files:
            Test(try formatting file)
    Test(clean up work)
```

I was wondering if there is a python library out there that handles test control. Obviously there is unittest but from what I can tell it's meant linear testing, i.e. testing with dependencies.

If unittest has this capability an example would be amazing.

*edit: What I'm really looking for is a framework with unittest like capabilities for error handling and assertions which allows me to write checks and have them plug into it.

Thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're asking, you're looking for something along the lines of Chai JS. Fortunately, someone has written a python library that approximates it, also called [Chai](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chai). Your testcase would look something like this:

```
FormatFilesCheck(files):
    expect(formatter.status).equals(installed)
    for prep in prework:
        do prep
        expect(prep).equals(what_prep_should_look_like)
        for file in files:
            format file
            expect(file).equals(what_file_should_look_like)
    clean up work
    # your expect/assert statements to make sure everything was cleaned up
```

Comment: Yeah similar to that just with a lot more infrastructure around it for handling the failures and logging out what happens. Basically a non-unit based unittest library, if that makes sense. Thanks!